# Form does not open to show information

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Good Night

I have a DGV that I fill out as follows:

```
dgView.addLinha("fase_origem", "metodoOrigem", "metodoChamador");
```

DataGridView:

```
public static void addLinha(string fase_origem, string metodoOrigem, string metodoChamador)
{
    try
    {
        if (DataConsole == null) return;

        var idLinha = DataConsole.Rows.Add();
        using (var linha = DataConsole.Rows[idLinha])
        {
            linha.Cells["dg_faseOrigem"].Value = fase_origem;
            linha.Cells["dg_metodoOrigem"].Value = metodoOrigem;
            linha.Cells["dg_metodoChamador"].Value = metodoChamador;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

I use a check to see if a file exists, in this check I try to insert information into the DGV (with the method above), but the program rotates and does not open the form. It is in a loop looking for the file (as expected) but the form does not open with the DGV and the information that should have been entered:

```
public static void JanelaFechada(IntPtr janela, string origem, string fase_origem, string metodo, string  metodoChamador)
{
    try
    {
        if (janela == (IntPtr)0)
        {
            dgView.addLinha("faseOrigem", "metodoOrigem" "metodoChamador";
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            string AtalhoExiste = "" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + Atalho + ".lnk";
            if (!File.Exists(AtalhoExiste))
            {
                dgView.addLinha("faseOrigem", "metodoOrigem" "metodoChamador";
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                JanelaFechada(janela, origem, fase_origem, metodo, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
            }
            else
            {
                dgView.addLinha("faseOrigem", "metodoOrigem" "metodoChamador";
                Abrir(origem, fase_origem, metodo, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

If I try to put information without this loop, the form opens normally with the information.

I tried to use a SplashScreen but I was also unsuccessful:

Is there any way to just start the system itself after the form with DGV appears and is ready to receive data?

Please, help-me!

Comment: Do you mean there is a loop using `JanelaFechada`?  My suggestion is remove `Thread.Sleep(1000);` in `JanelaFechada`. Also a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  would help your question get answer faster. Your code snippet is not enough for reproduce.

Comment: `JanelaFechada` is kinda weird, why do you need `Thread.Sleep` when setting/add a row in dgv?

Comment: The DGV works as a console, it is to have a space of time between a message and another one shown in the DGV.

Comment: On the loop, while a specific window is closed, it continues sending messages to the DGV until the user opens the window.

Comment: Hello there. You have a dead loop because you are calling the `JanelaFechada` again to check the same thing again which returns the same result again. If the file doesn't exist in the first check it won't exist in the second, third, ...etc. checks. So, just remove the line that calls the method again.  The third line in `if` block.

Comment: But this loop is expected, the problem is not opening the Form showing these checks in the DGV, the loop itself I will deal with later, there is still code to be done there .... My problem, or doubt, is why the form does not opens showing the DGV with what is being inserted with dgView.addLinha ("phaseOrigem", "metodoOrigem" "metodoChamador";

Comment: The idea now is to open the form with several equal lines in the DGV, from second to second until I make another detour or action.

Comment: The Form doesn't show because the infinite loop blocks the UI thread and prevent it from receiving the windows messages to do it's business. For now, call this function from the `Form.Shown` event instead of either `Form.Load` event or from the Form's constructor and see how it goes.

Comment: @JQSOFT Thanks to your explanations I was able to improve current codes and redesign future codes, thanks again.